# R turn each element in a vector into a list of lists

Tags: r, list

What is an efficient way to turn a list of elements into a list of lists with only one element in each list.  See example data below:

```
#This vector (but with many more elements) I'd like to turn into a list of list with one element in each. 
vector <- c("element1", "element2", "element3")

# It should look like this: 
list_vector <- list("element1", "element2", "element3")

#This is old: and not really how I want it: 
 
 list_vector <- list(list("element1"), list("element1"), list("element1"))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use

```
lapply(vector,list)
```

Edit: for new desired output

```
sapply(vector,list)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `as.list` will be an *efficient way* to turn each element of a vector into a list.
As your *list_vector* is an *unnamed* `list` you can use `as.list`, `lapply` or `sapply` to *turn each element of a vector into a list with only one element in each*.

```
x <- as.list(vector)
y <- lapply(vector, identity)
z <- unname(sapply(vector,list))
```

Test for Equality:

```
identical(x, list_vector)
[1] TRUE
identical(y, list_vector)
[1] TRUE
identical(z, list_vector)
[1] TRUE
```

Benchmark

````
x <- c("element1", "element2", "element3")

bench::mark("as.list" = as.list(x)
          , "lapply" = lapply(x, identity)
          , "sapply" = unname(sapply(x, list)))
#  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 as.list     1.19µs  1.76µs   493963.        0B     98.8  9998     2     20.2ms
#2 lapply      1.78µs  2.02µs   341163.        0B      0   10000     0     29.3ms
#3 sapply       9.6µs 10.94µs    81512.        0B     32.6  9996     4    122.6m```
````